# Google app-script .setValues() method is not writing to the Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

what i'm trying to do is to update data in a google sheet and then write that data back to the sheet.
1. I read the data from the spreadsheet 
2. Go over the data if needed i add a row and add columns, i.e. i change the existing data.
3. now i need to write the data back in the spreadhsheet

the only thing that i can think of is that the range is bigger than the old range of column and rows and this might be causing the problem

```
//Reading the data initially:

var workingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(storeSheetName);
var existingData = workingSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //row 0 is column names
//do some manipulations on the data (add rows and columns)
// Writing the values : 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(storeSheetName).getRange(1,1,existingData.length,storeColumns.length).setValue(existingData);
```

when i try running the script in debug mode , it keeps getting stuck on the .setValues() row and will not proceed

Comment: `storeSheetName` and `storeColumns` is undefined. So we can't verify the problem. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Could you please share the spreadsheet too, or perhaps a screenshot of what data currently exists and the expected data that needs to be updated using `setValues()`?

Comment: Hi, earlier there was an answer which provided the solution , it was deleted for some reason so i can not mark it as 'solution'